# Is locking necessary in this function?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-12/index.html) is an example of a mutex lock.

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
long long count;

void increment_count()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    count = count + 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
}

long long get_count()
{
    long long c;
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    c = count;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);

    return (c);
}
```

The document says that "The increment_count() function uses the mutex lock simply to ensure an atomic update of the shared variable". Ok, that's fine.

I have a problem with the way it explains the use of locking in get_count(): "The get_count() function uses the mutex lock to guarantee that the 64-bit quantity count is read atomically".

If I'm not wrong, right after unlocking `count_mutex` in `get_count` another thread can call `increment_count` and make the result from `get_count` incorrect. That's inevitable, right? Then why not just make this?

```
long long get_count()
{
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Because if not using ```pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);``` in ```get_count()``` function and simply using your suggested ```get_count()```, chances are high that another ```pthread``` modifies the ```count``` value in the middle of returning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The risk is not the wrong value, but an incoherent value.

Ie, getting a value that either count never held.

Suppose count goes from -1 to 0.  And the reader gets the high bytes while it is -1 and the low bytes while it is 0.  The reader reads 0xffffffff00000000, which is roughly 2^-32.

This is significantly different than any value it has ever held.

Things get even worse on some platforms.  One problem is multi-core cache consistency.  Locking operations map to not only mutually exclusive critical sections, but also requiring cache lines to be made consistent between CPU memory caches.

You can literally never see a change to a memory location if you don't get a lock in your thread.

Comment: In other words, what you mean to say is that in first clock cycle writer is writing 0x00000000 to the lower bytes (count is holding 0xffffffff00000000 in memory while updating -1 to 0 and reader calls it exactly at the same time) and in the next cycle writer is writing 0x00000000 to the higher bytes (count will have complete zeros in this cycle). In VLIW architecture probably long long are written at the same cycle itself I guess.

Comment: @HimanshuDutta that can depend on alignment.  Also, on some systems, a memory barrier is needed for cache consistency.

Comment: The risk is not only an incoherent value, but also that updates to the value are never observed in another thread *at all*.  More generally, without proper synchronization of access to shared variables, the program has undefined behavior.  That does not need to be limited to what values the reads observe.

Answer (score 1):

> Is locking necessary in this function?

**TL;DR: YES.**

From the perspective of the C language specification, the issue is:

> Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory
> location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.
>
> [...]
>
> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two
> conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not
> atomic, and neither happens before the other. **Any such data race
> results in undefined behavior**.

(C17 5.1.2.4/4,35; emphasis added)

Protecting *both* the read and the write via the same mutex is what ensures that there is a "happens before" relationship between every read and every write.  (Side note: what the spec means there by "atomic" is not what your document means when it says that protecting the write with a mutex makes it atomic.)

Undefined behavior applies to the whole program, not just the specific actions that trigger it, but the effects on the read are among the easiest to think about.  If the read were performed without locking the mutex, then it might

- Observe a value different from the variable's initial value and from any value that was written by any thread, OR
- Never observe values written by other threads at all, OR
- Over multiple reads, observe changes to the variable's value in a different order than they occurred, OR
- In combination with reads of other variables, observe a collection of values of different variables that never existed in memory together at the same time.

Comment: Do you have any resource that explains in more detail or gives examples of these effects and undefined behaviours?

Comment: I may have given you the wrong impression, @EmTor.  "Undefined behavior" means *anything at all* within the power of the computer might happen, any time you run the program.  The possibilities I listed are just a myopic view of few of the more likely immediate issues, based mostly on the behavior of cache memory, memory controllers, and CPU out-of-order execution capabilities. This is not a reference service, but Google is a fairly good one.  Examples abound here on SO, but they may be difficult to find.